# Cannot create/run React.js storybook (Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Trying to run **React.js** **storybook** using these [instructions](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/get-started/), running:

```
yarn storybook
```

but I get the following errors:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/taskbox/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
Referenced from: 
/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/taskbox/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
Expected in: flat namespace

error Command failed with signal "SIGABRT".
```

I tried removing the package.json file as well as all node_modules:

```
rm package.json
rm -r node_modules
```

...and again trying:

```
yarn storybook
```

...but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was the **version of node** that caused the problem.

I had originally installed Node using **brew**, which only provides an older version on install (v12.16.2 at the time of this writing). Not sure why brew doesn't provide the latest version.

Downloading node from their main [site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and running:

```
yarn storybook
```

...again solved the issue.